# Create a html element and find a div by id before adding in DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to find a the `div` with id **old-price**  and remove it, before inserting in the document ( before `main.appendChild(newDiv);`).

p.s.: Can't use **JQuery**

I already tried this:

> newDiv.getElementById("old-price").innerHTML = "";

but it **does not work**

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
var divString = "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>     <div class='thumbnail'>         <h1 class='text-center'> Black Shoes with red stripes </h1>         <img src='img/02.jpg'>         <small id='old-price' class='old-price'>250</small>         <p class='price'>250</p>         <a class='btn btn-primary'>BUY</a>     </div> </div> ";

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = divString;
//remove the div with id old-price
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.appendChild(newDiv);
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `newDiv.querySelector("#old-price").remove()`.

```js
var divString = "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>     <div class='thumbnail'>         <h1 class='text-center'> Black Shoes with red stripes </h1>         <img src='img/02.jpg'>         <small id='old-price' class='old-price'>250</small>         <p class='price'>250</p>         <a class='btn btn-primary'>BUY</a>     </div> </div> ";

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = divString;
//remove the div with id old-price
newDiv.querySelector("#old-price").remove()
var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.appendChild(newDiv);
```

```html
<div id="main">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var divString = "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4'>     <div class='thumbnail'>         <h1 class='text-center'> Black Shoes with red stripes </h1>         <img src='img/02.jpg'>         <small id='old-price' class='old-price'>250</small>         <p class='price'>250</p>         <a class='btn btn-primary'>BUY</a>     </div> </div> ";
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = divString;

//remove the old price
newDiv.getElementsByClassName("old-price")[0].innerHTML=""; 

var main = document.getElementById("main");
main.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I guess I will use it too (in another scenario)

Comment: Why does `getElementsByClassName` work when `getElementById` doesnt?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide it by this:

```
document.getElementById("old-price").style.display = 'none';
```

Or remove it as child from parent element (replace parent ID):

```
document.getElementById("parentID").removeChild("old-price");
```

Comment: The problem is I want to remove the div before adding to DOM, that's why I didn't tried with `document`, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: Ou that is true... :) Sorry my fail!